# Adjust picture size in picturelibrary webpart (ootb)

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a picture library webpart when I am adding this picture library webpart into the home page It will be more attractive but the size of picture inside the webpart is very small. I want to display this webpart with big pictures Please give any sugessions to do like this in ootb

```
.ExternalClass237F341FAE1F4564B3E1B16D76A5E0CA .ms-WPBody TD {
    BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: 0px; HEIGHT: auto !important; BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: 0px; VERTICAL-ALIGN: middle; BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: 0px; PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; PADDING-TOP: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 0px; MARGIN: 0px; PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; BORDER-TOP-WIDTH: 0px; WIDTH: auto !important
}
.ExternalClass237F341FAE1F4564B3E1B16D76A5E0CA .ms-WPBody TD DIV {
    BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: 0px; HEIGHT: auto !important; BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: 0px; VERTICAL-ALIGN: middle; BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: 0px; PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; PADDING-TOP: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 0px; MARGIN: 0px; PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; BORDER-TOP-WIDTH: 0px; WIDTH: 100% !important
}
.ExternalClass237F341FAE1F4564B3E1B16D76A5E0CA .ms-WPBody TD IMG {
    BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: 0px; HEIGHT: 190px !important; BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: 0px; VERTICAL-ALIGN: middle; BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: 0px; PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; PADDING-TOP: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 0px; MARGIN: 0px; PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; BORDER-TOP-WIDTH: 0px; WIDTH: 800px !important
}
.ExternalClass237F341FAE1F4564B3E1B16D76A5E0CA .s4-wpcell-plain {
    BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: 0px; HEIGHT: auto !important; BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: 0px; VERTICAL-ALIGN: middle; BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: 0px; PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; PADDING-TOP: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 0px; MARGIN: 0px; PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; BORDER-TOP-WIDTH: 0px; WIDTH: 100% !important
}
.ExternalClass237F341FAE1F4564B3E1B16D76A5E0CA .ms-PartSpacingVertical {
    MARGIN-TOP: 0px
}
.ExternalClass237F341FAE1F4564B3E1B16D76A5E0CA .style1 {
    COLOR: #808080
}</style><
```

Comment: plzz help me to do this in out of box??

Comment: Does the picture library webpart display the pictures in their native sizes? If so, wouldn't a small picture that is scaled up look poor?

Comment: no. The pics in picture libraray displays with small size.. If I increase MSOPictureLibrarySlideshowWebPart(its an id of image) width it cannot be reflected in pics of picture library.( the size of pic is also large but it displayedin small size itself)

Comment: this is the code for increasing the width of image in picture library webpart

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to reproduce the issue you are seeing. I suggest adding the web part to a blank web part page to see if anything else on the page is interfering.

Answer (score 0):

.ExternalClass237F341FAE1F4564B3E1B16D76A5E0CA .ms-WPBody TD {
    BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: 0px; HEIGHT: auto !important; BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: 0px; VERTICAL-ALIGN: middle; BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: 0px; PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; PADDING-TOP: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 0px; MARGIN: 0px; PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; BORDER-TOP-WIDTH: 0px; WIDTH: auto !important
}
.ExternalClass237F341FAE1F4564B3E1B16D76A5E0CA .ms-WPBody TD DIV {
    BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: 0px; HEIGHT: auto !important; BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: 0px; VERTICAL-ALIGN: middle; BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: 0px; PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; PADDING-TOP: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 0px; MARGIN: 0px; PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; BORDER-TOP-WIDTH: 0px; WIDTH: 100% !important
}
.ExternalClass237F341FAE1F4564B3E1B16D76A5E0CA .ms-WPBody TD IMG {
    BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: 0px; HEIGHT: 190px !important; BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: 0px; VERTICAL-ALIGN: middle; BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: 0px; PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; PADDING-TOP: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 0px; MARGIN: 0px; PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; BORDER-TOP-WIDTH: 0px; WIDTH: 800px !important
}
.ExternalClass237F341FAE1F4564B3E1B16D76A5E0CA .s4-wpcell-plain {
    BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: 0px; HEIGHT: auto !important; BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: 0px; VERTICAL-ALIGN: middle; BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: 0px; PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; PADDING-TOP: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 0px; MARGIN: 0px; PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; BORDER-TOP-WIDTH: 0px; WIDTH: 100% !important
}
.ExternalClass237F341FAE1F4564B3E1B16D76A5E0CA .ms-PartSpacingVertical {
    MARGIN-TOP: 0px
}
.ExternalClass237F341FAE1F4564B3E1B16D76A5E0CA .style1 {
    COLOR: #808080
}